# Bootstrap fixed navbar with collapsible fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a site with a fixed navbar and collapsible fixed sidebar, I came across one that is pretty great and does almost everything I want:

https://www.codeply.com/go/XJE8LOdX8k

The one problem is the fixed sidebar content, if there are too many items they will be cutoff, the solution would be to use a scrollbar but I can't seem to achieve the desired result because the fixed sidebar is being pushed down to appear below the navbar so the scrollbar does not appear completely, any help?

The desired result would be like the one on this site: https://www.minijuegos.com/

Comment: Put the code that reproduces the issue in the question. Have you forked the Codeply with your own example?

Comment: @Zim Something like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/woeJ9JxCQn notice how the end on the scrollbar is cut off, i want it to fit the screen.